# accessing static import of mother class in children class

Tags: java, inheritance, static-import

We have a helper class that we often include via static import to be able to concisely access its static methods and fields.

We have an abstract class whose children could benefit from this helper.
I was hoping to do the static import of the helper in the abstract class so that every sub-class can benefit from it, but it seems that Eclipse doesn't let me (import is deleted every time I save). Is it an Eclipse configuration problem? Or is it that the scope of the static import is limited to the class itself (and not its children).

Is there any other way to make the elements in the helper accessible to all the children classes without having to modify them each individually?

The helper:

```java
public class FormatHelper {
    
    public static final NL="\r\n";

    public static String bold(String val) {
        return "*" + val + "*";
    }
   
    public static String underline(String val) {
        return "+" + val + "+";
    }
}
```

Normal use of this helper:

```java
import static org.whatever.FormatHelper.NL
import static org.whatever.FormatHelper.bold
    
public class MyBusinessClass{
  
    public String doSomething(){
        return bold("much wow")+NL;  
    }
}
```

Now, I have an abstract class with around 20 subclasses, each of them needing to access bold/underline and some other static methods of FormatHelper.

I'd prefer not to have to write FormatHelper.NL every time, hence my wish to work with static imports.

I'd also prefer to have those elements in the subclasses scope from the get go. As, when creating new sub classes, I'd like to have a direct access to those methods, without having to think to add a static import.

Comment: Some lines of code are better than a long description

Comment: You can't do that. An import is not inherited. It makes no sense. An import is merely saying "I want to use a shorter name for these classes/methods in this file".

Comment: Not to your question, but **please** change `NL` to use `System.lineSeparator();` -- hardcoding for Windows is not a best practice.

Comment: @Eliott, it's not windows related. It's actually for Jira at the moment, but we want to centralize those formatting rules to make the migration easier in case we decide not to use jira anymore

Comment: @RealSkeptic Makes sense, I'm so not used to write imports (as they are automatically generated) that I thought what was already imported in the abstract class was directly accessible to the children classes (as I imagined children classes as a direct extension of the mother class).
How would you solve this problem then ?is there any paradigm I'm unfamiliar with that could be used there ?

That's why I'd expect the static imports to be visible "usable" in the children classes

Comment: I would just type the name of the method and then let the IDE suggest the import and accept that suggestion. Also for future reference, if people make suggestion in the comments, 1) don't make assumptions they are the downvoter (you have no way of knowing that unless they explicitly say they downvoted you), and 2) don't include snarky replies/comments in your edit: that will only invite more downvotes and is unlikely to get your question reopened (not to mention that it is technically a violation of the "be nice" policy, and could get you suspended).

Comment: I've known programmers that would use ` interface FormatHelper` with final static fields, default methods (replace static), and then add `implements FormatHelper` everywhere. It does what you asked for but IMO style is ugly (and I would fail it in code review), These days "import static FormatHelper.* with good IDE code organiser will cleanup the dependencies neatly.

Comment: @DuncG Thanks for your input. To tell you the truth, I thought of doing it, but it doesn't really work in my case as I have also methods I'd like to share that way.

At the end of the day, I think I'll refactorize this Helper into a Builder class. It's a bit more effort, but it's certainly what's cleanest.
That builder can then be instantiated once in the abstract class and once in each other class that used to refer to the helper.

Comment: @LoïcGammaitoni - methods also work via the interface, but `bold` would have to be `default` rather than `static`

Comment: ooh, I wasn't aware the keyword default was a thing. That's actually pretty neat. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you could specify the format helper code is in an interface. You would need to change the static methods to default methods to allow the methods to be accessible in other classes without `ClassName.` prefix:

```
public interface FormatHelper {
    public static final String NL= System.lineSeparator() ; // or "\r\n" if targetting Windows from non-Windows

    public default String bold(String val) {
        return "*" + val + "*";
    }

    public default String underline(String val) {
        return "+" + val + "+";
    }
}
```

Then the helper code definitions can be accessed from any implementing classes (abstract or otherwise):

```
import xyz.FormatHelper;

public class MyBusinessClass implements FormatHelper {
    public String doSomething(){
        return bold("much wow")+NL;
    }
}
```

Any class derived from `MyBusinessClass` would be able to access the same methods and fields without further imports, and without "FormatHelper." prefix.

NOTE: this mechanism would not work within static methods of the calling classes, which may be a significant problem.